# iOs Programming - Block a contact

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

Hi Is there any way to block my iPhone from calling/sending text to a contact and receiving text and call from a contact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible, there isnt any public legal way to do it in the iOS, you can either place a call, or send an sms, and that is all you can do with call and sms in the ios